# Multiple GDAL operations on Raster Dataset without opening and closing files multiples times

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, gdal, hillshade

I'm going to start writing a script, likely in python, where I need to open a raster file, reproject it, multiply it with a slope-shaded elevation model then save the full res outcome as well as multiple downsampled versions in specific resolutions (1m, 2m, 4m, 8m, 16m, 32m).

My question is, how do I go about opening a file and doing multiple operations on it, then save the outcome without the overhead of opening, exporting,  then opening exported files for the next operation, multiple files along the way using gdal libraries? 
I'm basically trying to stay away from using each gdal terminal program individually as linking those programs together causes lots of disk reads and writes..

I'm hoping for a general example, even if it doesn't do the same functions that I'm looking for.

Comment: see if https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html helps

Comment: I was looking at that. If I had another real life example then I think between the 2 I can figure it out.